# ROS Answers SE migration: groovy rospack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a starter on ROS. I got Ubuntu and groovy installed on my Linux Laptop. I am going through tutorials and got till rospack. When I tried "rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials", I got segmentation fault (core dump).

Till this point the software behaved per tutorials

Any suggestions?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52587/groovy-rospack/) by [goman1](https://answers.ros.org/users/3988/goman1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's [one ticket already reported and fixed](https://github.com/ros/rospack/issues/4) that Debian-build might not be available yet.

ps. However I can't be sure enough that the issue is exactly the same with this limited amount of info. @goman1 can you see [this similar thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/51555/beginner-tutorials-segmentation-fault-with-rospack-depends1/?comment=51762#comment-51762) first and give us the backtrace of the debugger?

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0